EasyOCR not writing output to file on a different system
I am working on an OCR project using the EasyOCR library. I wrote a Python script on my system that works perfectly fine, but when I run the same script on a different system, the output is not being written to the text file.
Here is my code:
import os
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['fa'])

folder_path = 'images/'
output_file = 'output.txt'

with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i, image_name in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_path), 1):
        image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, image_name)
        result = reader.readtext(image_path, detail=0, paragraph=True)
        f.write(f"image {i}:\n")
        f.write("\n".join(result))
        f.write("\n------------------------------\n")


The problem:
On my system, this code processes all the images in the images/ folder and writes the detected text to output.txt. However, on another system:
It processes only one image.
No text is written to the output file (it stays empty).
I even tried adding a simple f.write("Hello") inside the loop, but still, nothing is written to the file.
What I’ve tried:
Both systems are using the same versions of Python and EasyOCR.
The images/ folder exists and contains the correct images on both systems.
The file paths are valid, and there are no errors in reading the images.
What could be causing this issue on the second system, and why is nothing being written to the output file?
Any help would be appreciated!
